# meet error while trying to read int number from input file

Tags: c++

I am new to coding C++. I meet issue while trying to read 2 int number from input file, calculate them and then export to output. System showing issue at line 14,18 and 21 of the loop. Please give me advice on this. Thanks all!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream file;
file.open("input.txt");
string word;
word.clear();
int a, b;
int count = 0;
while(file>>word)
{
    count++;
    if (count % 2 == 1){
        a = stoi(word);
    }
    else {
        b = stoi(word);
    }
}
int TOTAL = a + b;
int Difference = a - b;
int Multiply = a * b;
int Division = a / b;
int MUD = a % b;
ofstream out("output.txt");

out << "Input Values: " << a << " " << b << endl;
out << "Sum of two numbers: " << TOTAL << endl;
out << "Difference of two numbers: " << Difference << endl;
out << "Multiply of two numbers: " << Multiply << endl;
out << "Division of two numbers: " << Division << endl;
out << "Modular division of two numbers: " << MUD << endl;
cout << "Calculation written in file" << endl;
out.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you give sample data in file??

Comment: Sample in file: 12 2

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/SubtleNimbleEvents Go to this link your code is working properly you can check

Comment: So problem maybe in my visual studio? Its showing this error:

Comment: yeah may be can you edit your code and paste error message also?

Comment: Severity Code Description Line
Error (active) E0349 no operator ">>" matches these operands 14
Error (active) E0020 identifier "stoi" is undefined 18
Error (active) E0020 identifier "stoi" is undefined 21
Error C2679 binary '>>': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 14
Error C3861 'stoi': identifier not found 18
Error C3861 'stoi': identifier not found 21

Comment: Try including `<string>`

Comment: `#include <string>` because you are using string functions

Comment: Its worked!. Thanks you guys a lot. Have a good night!

Answer (score 0):

`#include <string>` because you are using string functions that's the problem I think